# BCS state with finite current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

How is the BCS state and associated BdG quasiparticle hamiltonian altered by the presence of a finite current? Is there a standard text where this is discussed? (I didn't see anything in Altland and Simons or Tinkham).

My guess would be that:

1. The Fermi surface is displaced to have average momentum $q$
2. The Cooper pairs have finite net momentum (which I guess for a general bare dispersion depends on their position on the Fermi surface), and have on average momentum $q$
3. The pairing potential (i.e. the order parameter) obtains a corresponding position dependent phase.
4. The superconducting gap becomes anisotropic even for s-wave superconductors.
5. The minimum gap goes to zero at the critical current.
6. If the BdG hamiltonian is symmetric under inversion $(x) \to (- x)$ this is broken to $(x,q) \to (-x, -q)$ (i.e. inversion combined with reversal of the current). And similarly for time reversal symmetry.
7. These properties can be derived by repeating the usual field theoretic BCS derivation (vis-a-vis Altland and Simons) with a Lagrange multiplier coupled to the current operator to enforce the finite current.

Are these expectations correct?

I would be very grateful if someone knows a reference which discusses this as I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: A very detailed discussion (perhaps even too detailed) is found in the book "Quantum Liquids" by Anthony J. Leggett

Comment: @KFGauss thank you.